# I would like to display a csv file in QtableView of PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I designed the layout of the GUI on QtDesigner and converted it into a python file. I've searched already existing questions for a solution but either I missed it or there isn't one. I would like to display my csv file on the table view of the GUI.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import csv

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    
    #def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 21, 761, 361))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        #self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 430, 161, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 420, 141, 81))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadCsv)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        
        
    def loadCsv(self):
        fileName = 'C:/Users/Rada1/Desktop/data.csv'
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this code I get the error

`AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'model'`

I then tried to initialize `self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)` to the Ui_MainWindow Class but instead got the error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QStandardItemModel(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
  QStandardItemModel(int, int, parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is explicit: `QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent)` expects a `QObject` as `parent`; you are giving it an `object`.

So you may for instance add these two lines in setupUi:

```
self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(MainWindow)
self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But for some reason the tableview display leaves an empty space after each row from the csv file.